# IE 11: How to Open JavaScript genereted file without Open/Save dialog?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, pdf, blob

I'm working on an Angular application and one of features is to open PDF and JSON files returned from a ReST service. Actually, a file opening must be performed without any Open/Save dialog.

This works in Google Chrome using code below and "Always open with...":

```
var a = document.createElement("a");
a.href = URL.createObjectURL(blobObject);
a.download = fileName;
a.dataset['downloadurl'] = [mimeType, a.download, a.href].join(':');
a.target = "_blank";
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
```

Problem is Internet Explorer - IE11 doesn't support PDF like data-url. And because of that I was implemented msSaveOrOpenBlob():

```
navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blobObject, fileName);
```

But problem is that IE always shows Open/Save dialog, so there is no direct file opening. This works with download file using , but not with msSaveOrOpenBlob().

Any ideas to solve this?

Comment: `download` attribute has limited browser support  http://caniuse.com/#search=download

Answer (score 0):

IE provides the limited support for data-url but I've experienced the limitation at 128KB on the data-url data length for PDF files in the latest Chrome 12 (both Mac and Windows version). The Chrome v12 just fails silently and displays an empty page.

So the only really reliable way is to display the PDF file on click is save the PDF to the server and have a user to click on the server-side link.